# Any reason to use JSONP instead of CORS?

Tags: http, cors, jsonp

My understanding is that JSONP is kind of hacky way of implementing something that could be done using CORS. Still I see people asking questions of how to use JSONP even if they have access to services and can configure CORS. That makes me wonder if there any good reason to use JSONP instead of CORS?

Answer (score 0):

In nowadays, I think that the main advantage of `JSONP` is that it will work with older browsers. So, if you need to support IE <= 7, FF <= 3.5, etc. - `JSONP` is your option. That's it.